# 500 error in Ajax Get

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a dropdownlists selected value to controller and retrieve json data back.

When I debug, parameter gets to controller nicely, values are retrieved nicely but after return part on console it says

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`"

This is my controller action: (in `WebContentsController`)

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetWebContentTypeDetails (int id)
{
    var details = db.WebContentTypeDetail.Where(x=>x.WebContentTypeID == id).ToList();
    return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this is JS part (printing it to console for testing)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#WebContentTypeID").change(function () {
        var ChangedID = $('#WebContentTypeID option:selected').val();
        alert(ChangedID);
        $.getJSON('/webcontents/GetWebContentTypeDetails/' + ChangedID, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
});
```

EDIT:

WebContentTypeDetail model

```
public partial class WebContentTypeDetail
    {
        public int WebContentTypeDetailID { get; set; }
        public int WebContentTypeID { get; set; }
        public string DetailKey { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> Rank { get; set; }

        public virtual WebContentType WebContentType { get; set; }
    }
```

WebContentType model

```
public partial class WebContentType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public WebContentType()
        {
            this.WebContent = new HashSet<WebContent>();
            this.WebContentTypeDetail = new HashSet<WebContentTypeDetail>();
        }

        public int WebContentTypeID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string CreatedByUserID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string LastEditedByUserID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastEditDate { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<WebContent> WebContent { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<WebContentTypeDetail> WebContentTypeDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the model for `WebContentTypeDetail` and any models that it also contains

Comment: Are you able to run the debugger when doing the request? What is in the details variable?

Comment: Details returns exactly what I need, that part is allright

Comment: The issue is that `WebContentTypeDetail` contains a property which is typeof `WebContentType` and `WebContentType` contains a proeprty which is a collection of `WebContentTypeDetail` which creates a circular reference exception. As noted in your previous question, you need to return only those properties you need in the view (using a collection of a view model or anonymous objects)

Comment: How can I do it ? I came across this question and accepted answer looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic

Comment: Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402894/return-jsonresult-with-list-of-objects-from-mvc-controller/25403595#25403595). We cant give you the code because we don't know which properties you need in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly return a entity list from context query result, because they are not serializable in most of cases, especially in your case: entities got a loop references.

you have 2 options:

```
var details = db.WebContentTypeDetail.Where(x=>x.WebContentTypeID == id)
```

1. map your result to anonymous object list:

   ```
   return Json(details.select(x=>new {
     //you data structure
   }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```
2. create your view model and mark it `[Serializable]`, then return necessary data to client:

   ```
   return Json(details.select(x=>new YourViewModel {
    //you data structure
   }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#WebContentTypeID").change(function () {
    var ChangedID = $('#WebContentTypeID option:selected').val();
    alert(ChangedID);
    $.getJSON('/webcontents/GetWebContentTypeDetails?id=' + ChangedID, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
});
```

As parameter id should be passed as querystring. And if you're using mvc then url should be passed in @url.action so it must be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#WebContentTypeID").change(function () {
    var ChangedID = $('#WebContentTypeID option:selected').val();
    alert(ChangedID);
 var URL = @Url.Action("_GetWebContentTypeDetails", "webcontents");

    $.getJSON(URL + '?id=' + ChangedID, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
});
```

Comment: the issue is not in routing, 500 means: the request arrives right location, but server side code did not work.  and if the scripts is in xxx.js file, your razor code won't work as well. and `Url.Action` return action result, not a url, it should be `Url.ActionLink`. and never try to do your first code, it won't pass code review.