# Returning the json data from MVC4 Controller to ajax (not Working)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am returning the data from mvc to ajax. but the array is not rendering to ajax success function gives the **Internal Server error** . my code is appended below.

**My Ajax call :**

```
 $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/getallNews/",

            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);

            }
                 , function (error) {
                     alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                 }
});
```

**And MVC Controller Action :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult getallNews()
    {
        //var id = 16;

       var Returnmodel = _newsRepository.GetAll().ToList();

        return Json(Returnmodel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response. What are the details of the error?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EntityNews_A56D36119E4D7880562B6207DD29EC42DDA0BAED4A20567E748CC8A346B9E1EE'.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:31781/Home/getallNews/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:31781
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: @StephenMuecke check these error produced in network log

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402894/return-jsonresult-with-list-of-objects-from-mvc-controller/25403595#25403595) for an explanation. Return a collection of anonymous objects or view models containing only the properties you need

Comment: And edit your question with the relevant details.

Comment: as you can see the attached images some of the forigen keys are also comming from entity. how can i reomove so specific columns from entitry??

Comment: Read my previous comment - and read the link!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks it works for me

Answer (score 1):

**Change your ajax call to :**

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Home/getallNews/",
                type: "POST",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
            },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Neither of these are necessary and this has nothing at all to do with OP's issue

Answer (score 0):

Add contenttype and datatype in your the Ajax call as Below

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("getallNews","Home")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },                                
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Neither of these are necessary and this has nothing at all to do with OP issue

Comment: did you add any authorize attribute in top?