# How to access values in items in ViewData?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    List<branchInformation> branches = ViewData["branch"] as          List<branchInformation>;
}
<div class="col" style="width:100%">    
     <div class="form-group">
          Branch:
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.brh_shp_to,
        from i in branches
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = i.brhNm,
            Value = i.brhAddr.ToUpper().Replace(@"\N", "\n")
        }
        ,
         new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%", @id = "brh" })

     </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
     <div class="form-group">
          Ship To Address
          <br />
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.brh_shp_to_addr, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100%; max-height:130px; height:130px", @id = "shpAddr" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.brh_shp_to_addr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#brh').change(function () {
        var brhName = $('#brh option:selected').val();
        $('#shpAddr').val(@branches.Where(i=>i.brhNm == brhName).FirstOrDefault().brhAddr).val());       

    });
</script>
```

Model

```
public class OrderModels
{
    public OrderModels()
    {
       this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string brh_shp_to { get; set; }
    public string brh_shp_addr { get; set; }
}
```

At first, Dropdown display Branch Name, and its value is Branch Address. What I intend to do is to save the text in drop down as ***brh_shp_to*** , and its Value will be saved to ***brh_shp_addr***, but after I send an ajax call, the model takes the value and saved it ***brh_shp_to***, not the text that I want.

So, I changed the code to have text and value be brhNm and have a different event to detect the change and update textarea to be brhAddr by comparing the value of dropdown selected to ***ViewData["branch"]*** which is now a list of branch.

I want to change value in ***shpAddr*** textarea to the address value of the branch upon changing option in the dropdown.

All the code are wrapped in

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxEditOrder", "Orders",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure",
        LoadingElementId = "progress"
    }))
    {
    }
```

I got error saying that brhName is not defined.

Comment: `@branches.Where(..)` is server side code. `brhName` is a JavaScript variable (client side code) that does not exist on the server - its not in scope. You can use ajax to call a controller method that returns the value you want based on the selected option (or if the collection is relatively small, you can convert `branches` to a javascript array and store and access it)

Comment: Stephen,

I tried using
var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["branch"]))');
 but it says a circular reference was detected.

Comment: Then you data is far too complex to be doing that anyway - and the error means your model contains a property that is itself a complex object which has a property that is the model (hence the circular reference)

Comment: Refer also [Return JsonResult with List of objects from MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402894/return-jsonresult-with-list-of-objects-from-mvc-controller/25403595#25403595)

Comment: I see, let me try to create a temp model to see if it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comment, my model was too complex, so I created a small model and transfer only part of attributes I needed in there.

```
public class BranchInfo
{
    public string brhNm { get; set; }
    public string brhAddr { get; set; }
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#brh').change(function () {
        var brhName = $('#brh option:selected').val();
        var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(branches))');


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].brhNm == brhName)
        {
                $('#shpAddr').val(data[i].brhAddr);
        }
     }
</script>
```

This works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing quotes on your javascript?

change:

```
$('#shpAddr').val(@branches.Where(i=>i.brhNm == brhName).FirstOrDefault().brhAddr).val());
```

To

```
$('#shpAddr').val('@branches.Where(i=>i.brhNm == brhName).FirstOrDefault().brhAddr').val());  //not sure what brhAddr holds. you might also have th remove the last .val() on this line.
```

Comment: Sorry. It does not work. Code still throw error saying brhName is not in current context.